# Windows 7 BSOD when changing power plan

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, bsod, minidumps

i have a strange problem. When i want to change the power plan on my laptop from High performance to Balanced, Windows freezes and i get bsod. The power plan settings are all default.

Laptop specs:
 - Intel Core i3 330M/350M
- Intel® HM55 Express Chipset
- DDR3 1066 MHz SDRAM 8GB
- ATI Mobility™ Radeon HD5730 1GB DDR3 VRAM
- Intel SSD330 128gb
- Windows 7 Home premium
I've searched the internets but couldnt find a similar issue. BSOD first started when i installed this SSD and stopped when i've updated the chipset controller driver then started again yesterday when i wanted to change the power settings plan.[Minidump file here.](http://www.speedyshare.com/Q5Wvp/053114-9344-01.zip)

Any help with this weird issue appriciated, thanks.

---

Edit:
 - i've ran Memory diagnostic tool,
 - Intel SSD diagnostics
 - and updated the firmware to 3.2.1.
Non of these steps worked or shown signs of errors - but still got BSOD when changing power plan settings.

After analizing the dump file via osronline.com here is Dump Header Information:

`` DUMP_HEADER64:
MajorVersion        0000000f
MinorVersion        00001db1
KdSecondaryVersion  00000000
DirectoryTableBase  00000001e33ef000
PfnDataBase         fffff80003310278
PsLoadedModuleList  fffff800032a6890
PsActiveProcessHead fffff80003288590
MachineImageType    00008664
NumberProcessors    00000004
BugCheckCode        000000f4
BugCheckParameter1  0000000000000003
BugCheckParameter2  fffffa8008661b30
BugCheckParameter3  fffffa8008661e10
BugCheckParameter4  fffff800033de270
KdDebuggerDataBlock fffff800`032520a0
ProductType         00000001
SuiteMask           00000310
WriterStatus        00000000
MiniDumpFields      00000cff ``

TRIAGE_DUMP64:
ServicePackBuild      00000100 
SizeOfDump            00040000 
ValidOffset           0003fffc 
ContextOffset         00000348 
ExceptionOffset       00000f00 
MmOffset              00002080 
UnloadedDriversOffset 000020d0 
PrcbOffset            00002260 
ProcessOffset         00006f60 
ThreadOffset          00007430 
CallStackOffset       000078d8 
SizeOfCallStack       00000cc8 
DriverListOffset      000088e0 
DriverCount           0000009a 
StringPoolOffset      0000df80 
StringPoolSize        000033c0 
BrokenDriverOffset    00000000 
TriageOptions         ffffffff 
TopOfStack            fffff880`03c3c0e8 
BStoreOffset          00000000 
SizeOfBStore          00000000 
LimitOfBStore         00000000`00000000 
DebuggerDataOffset    000085a0 
DebuggerDataSize      00000340 
DataBlocksOffset      00011340 
DataBlocksCount       00000013 
  fffff800`032a6ce0 - fffff800`032a6d7b at offset 00011470
  fffff800`0328eb48 - fffff800`0328eb4b at offset 0001150c
  fffff800`0328eb44 - fffff800`0328eb47 at offset 00011510
  fffff800`03217880 - fffff800`0321797f at offset 00011514
  fffffa80`08661000 - fffffa80`08661fff at offset 00011614
  fffff800`033de000 - fffff800`033defff at offset 00012614
  fffff800`032dd600 - fffff800`032dd603 at offset 00013614
  fffff800`032dd200 - fffff800`032dd28f at offset 00013618
  fffff800`0331007c - fffff800`0331007f at offset 000136a8
  fffff800`03310068 - fffff800`0331006b at offset 000136ac
  fffffa80`06c69660 - fffffa80`06c69847 at offset 000136b0
  fffffa80`09571000 - fffffa80`09571767 at offset 00013898
  fffff800`0327a280 - fffff800`0327a287 at offset 00014000
  fffff800`0327a288 - fffff800`0327a28f at offset 00014008
  fffffa80`06d1c000 - fffffa80`06d1c11f at offset 00014010
  fffff800`0327a290 - fffff800`0327a297 at offset 00014130
  fffff800`0327a298 - fffff800`0327a29f at offset 00014138
  fffff880`03c3c000 - fffff880`03c3cfff at offset 00014140
  fffff800`030d8000 - fffff800`030d8fff at offset 00015140
  Max offset 16140, 2d4f0 from end of file

**-- Solution --**
Provided by Vinayak: After installing the Intel Rapid storage Technology from MajorGeeks, i didn't experience a BSOD since, thank you :)

Comment: Does the problem happen every time you try to change the power plan? If so, which exact settings are you using?

Comment: Yes, i was using the default High performance plan and after switching to Balanced (also default settings), disk crashed (bsod).

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the minidump and after a little bit of searching, I found [this forum post](http://www.sevenforums.com/bsod-help-support/242700-bsod-suspend-recovery.html).

The guy seems to have a similar problem and it looks like the SSD was to blame for it.

Try [updating your SSD firmware](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=18455) to the latest version available. Also update Intel's Rapid Storage Technology Driver (RST) driver and AHCI drivers for your notebook from [ASUS support](http://support.asus.com/download/options.aspx?SLanguage=en&type=1).

If updating your drivers from ASUS's support site doesn't work, try installing [this driver package from MajorGeeks](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/intel_rapid_storage_technology_driver.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your instructions - by installing the driver package from MajorGeeks i was able to change the power plan normaly and i didn't get bsod :)

Comment: Awesome! Could you please update your question and add some more details about the BSOD so other users who face the same problem can find this answer?

Comment: You can analyze the minidump [here](http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=analyze). Please add the first few lines of the analysis to the question. Particularly, the "Dump Header Information" and "Debugging Details" section.

Comment: Great, updated.

Answer (score 0):

DD5

While you are at it you really should update Related to ATK64AMD.sys ATK0100 ACPI Utility from ASUS.  Yours is from 2006

Comment: thx m8, will do :)